# How do I use pyautogui.locateOnScreen() for multiple images in multiple regions?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to search for multiple objects in multiple regions of my screen and click on them if any are found.

So far I've been able to get it to work for single objects but I'm now trying to adapt my code for multiple objects and I'm getting the error: `expected an image filename, OpenCV NumPy array, or PIL image` I've tried using both filenames and NumPy arrays detailed below.

I've tried with `i = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` to load my images into an OpenCV NumPy array and without, by loading in image files directly and I get the same error with both.

When I check the debugger `cv.imread` is showing numpy arrays `array([[[124, 23, 1... ype=unit8)` and without `cv.imread` and loading the images directly I can see `[C:\\Users\\expected.jpg]`

```
import pyautogui as py
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import PIL.ImgeOps import grayscale

def missions(a):

      for x in range (0, a):
        regions = {
        "region 1": (412,169,473,251),
        "region 2": (428,687,457,733),
        "region 3": (1278,161,1309,223),
        "region 4": (1266,673,1322,753)
        }

        # intalise empty array
        missionShipList = []
        # Get list of all files from directory
        directory = glob.glob( r"C:\users\stevphen\*.jpg")
        
        # add images to array
        for file in directory:
            if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg'):
                missionShipList.append(file)
        
        if missionShipList is None:
            print("failed to load template.")
            quit()

        for x in range (0, a):
            for region_name, region in regions.items():
                missionShips = py.locateOnScreen(missionShipList, region=region, grayscale=True, confidence=0.86)
                if missionShips != None:
                    print(f"Cicked a mission ship in {region_name}")
                    py.click(missionShips)

missions(3)
```

And I've also tried using `im.read` to add the images to my array:

```
    for file in directory:
        cv.imread(file, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        missionShipList.append(file)
```

Showing variable populated as expected:

[image: Showing variable populated]

I've also tried looping through the images individually and removing grayscale. Same error.

```
    for x in range (0, a):
        for region_name, region in regions.items():
            for ships in missionShipList:
                py.locateOnScreen(missionShipList, region=region, confidence=0.86)
```

What do I need to change to load my images correctly and why is the debugger showing missionShipList is populated while `locateOnScreen` is throwing an error?

Comment: calling something `list` is a bad idea because that's the `list` type in python -- `img` is undefined in the loop -- please practice debugging python code. look for learning material.

Comment: That's actually mostly my inability to draft example code apologies. I'll update with the actual code being used now. The main issue that I have is that both version I've tried are showing correctly in the debugger they have correctly loaded objects. I'm getting both the numpy array showing or the full file path showing the image. Either should work but both are giving me the same error.

Comment: that code right now isn't much better. no pseudocode. *the code* you actually *execute*. we aren't discussing philosophy or math here, but computer code. no handwaving, no "that should be obvious from context".

Comment: I thought I was meant to upload pseudocode to StackOverflow. I've updated it with the actual code I am executing.